# How to implement a floating "New Mail Button" similar to gmail in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to add a button like the "New Mail" button in the Gmail app (The circle button bottom of right with pen icon), which is floating on the screen. Can someone show me how to do this in ios?

Gmail floating button

[image]

Comment: Place the view in a window above the main window.

Comment: Thanks!! any sample for refference?

Comment: No, but look at the `windowLevel` property of `UIWindow`.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout these library

For swift -

```
https://github.com/yoavlt/LiquidFloatingActionButton
```

For Objective C -

```
https://github.com/gizmoboy7/VCFloatingActionButton
```

Comment: in swift 3 is not working. is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

in storyboard

for Button

1. set trailing space & bottom space to main view (Ex : 10 Bottom space & 10 Trailing Space)
2. then set Ratio 1:1 & width(or height)  Fix (Ex: 25)
3. set pen Icon Image in Button

Now in ViewController File make outlet of Button (Ex: floatingButton)

```
_floatingButton.layer.cornerRadius=_floatingButton.frame.size.width/2;
_floatingButton.imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
_floatingButton.layer.borderWidth=0.5f;
```